# Pushing multiple updates for fusion charts

Tags: java, fusioncharts

I'm using zoomline fusion charts to display on UI, by using AJAX i'm getting data `@label=4:20PM,4:30PM&ToolText=123,515,4125|635,125,452,369&value=1,1,1,1|2,2,2,2`.

How can I add this data to my zoomline chart? My chart is initially loaded with JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/real-time-charts#push-multiple-updates) hope it will help you out

The example below shows the format used to push multiple updates at one time:

&label=11:45:55,11:46:00,11:46:05&value=22,27,28|7,6,5